# Paypal SDK and credit card payment

Tags: cordova, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to implement a payment system for Android and iOS application with Phonegap. I started working with Phonegap plugin for Android and iOS SDK of Paypal REST API - and everything is fine with Sandbox testing. But with LIVE account, message is appearing that ‘your account is not eligible for credit card transfer’. I assume, for that I would need US based developer/paypal account?

I just want to implement a credit card payment system for my app. Is it too hard and complicated? Can I do this with Paypal SDK? If yes, how? If no, do we have any other payment SDK which accepts credit card for physical goods? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

See the [PayPal docs](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/#direct-credit-card-payments) for countries where you can use the Direct Credit Card payments feature.